# ¿Cómo convertir un arreglo de objetos tipo [{name: valor}...] en un arreglo de valores?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo convertir esto

```
[{"name":"All"},{"name":"NodeJS"},{"name":"ReactJS"},{"name":"PHP"},{"name":"Wordpress"},{"name":"Joomla"}]
```

En esto

```
["All", "NodeJS", "ReactJS", "PHP", "Wordpress", "Joomla"]
```

Talvez sea una cosa muy simple pero ni idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar la función [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

```js
let data = [{"name":"All"},{"name":"NodeJS"},{"name":"ReactJS"},{"name":"PHP"},{"name":"Wordpress"},{"name":"Joomla"}];

let values = data.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.name;
});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que acceder al atributo `name` recorriendo con `foreach`

```js
var datos=[{"name":"All"},{"name":"NodeJS"},{"name":"ReactJS"},{"name":"PHP"},{"name":"Wordpress"},{"name":"Joomla"}];
var copy=[];
datos.forEach(function(current){
copy.push(current.name);
})

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 1):

con este código, los valores se almacenan en `a`

```js
var a = [] // ["All", "NodeJS", "ReactJS", "PHP", "Wordpress", "Joomla"]
var b = [{"name":"All"},{"name":"NodeJS"},{"name":"ReactJS"},{"name":"PHP"},{"name":"Wordpress"},{"name":"Joomla"}]

for (i in b){
  a.push(b[i].name)
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que lo que quieres es llevar de json a un obj de js y no aun arreglo                   te voy a poner un ejemplo:

```
          var obj = { 
            JSONObject: [], //[] col
            cantidad: 0, //>= 0
            construct: function(JSON_) {
               this.JSONObject = eval("(" + JSON_ + ")"); //err...              

            },
            stringify: function() { return JSON.stringify(this.JSONObject); } //err... //JSON: function() { return '{ "id": "' + this.id + '", "nombre": "' + this.nombre + '"}'; }

        };
```

donde obtienes el json:

```
        var json=data; // data:[{'id'=>1,'nombre':Omar},{'id'=>2,'nombre':Daniel}]
        obj.construct(json);
        alert(obj.JSONObject[0].nombre); //Debe salir Omar
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Tratar de evitar en lo posible el uso de `eval`; se puede usar para explotar uno q otro bug.